# Embedding a UITextView in an image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uitextview

I have a UIImageView displaying a picture that I took with the iPhone Camera.
On top of that, I have a UITextView in which the user can type stuff that describes the picture.

I would like to create a combined image of the two views and send it to a server.

Anyone knows how I can do that (just creating the image.  I know how to send it)

Answer (score 1):

If the UIImageView and UITextView are contained in another UIView. Or if you can create a UITextView and UIImageView on the same UIView you can then do this.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Where myView is equal to the UIView containing the two.

You can also draw each one separately (by setting the frame appropriately) into myView to accomplish the same thing.